Wrapper Funcion that Receives and Executes Generic Funcion Returns Error When Executing
I have a wrapper function that recieves an async generic function and runs it, but it doesn't honor the return type.
In this case, the generic function returns a type of response and the wrapper function has a return type annotation that indicates the return of the result of the inner function. The code runs and works well but typescript yells inside the function that the response cannoot be returned. I think it doesn't have to do with the promise because I tried with a function without a promise and it didn't work either.
interface Response {
  status: "error" | "success";
  message?: string;
  data?: any;
}


export const actionWrapper = async <
  T extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<Response>,
>(
  action: T,
): Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>> => {
    const res = await action();
    return res;
};


Playground Code: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4AcD2IMoDeAUMshmHGAK4YBcyARNFDlI8gD5MbUJIYMjANylkAW0wY4AcwgB+BhSigZosgBMqcRcjggAnqIC+xMxAAeuKGGQI8FPQjDA8AdShwsWaMgC8ehgGIAjIADxiACrIlpAgGhjIABQAdGlwUDL0eoYA2gC6AJT+AHzIAAqs4sAEYejYDhAlADTEJUliiC54DJGthQyVONW1AIIA7nDAkBp1EDRQIJEGPmGRJRulyCRkZPb4tlCY-nqT007dIEmF6rtHCyDIRxgmokA
